# Two login pages in authentication in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project, MVC 4, I want to use two login pages, one for admin, one for customers.
But in the web.config file, only one login page can be used. Plese help me what should I do.

Comment: If there are two login pages for the same application, you really wont know who is an admin until they login. 
You can always have two serparate views for the logins but am not sure if the design is sound.

Answer (score 0):

Like Nanda suggested - if both login pages are using the same type of authentication then it might be worth looking at your design as this doesn't sound right.

But if you want to use a two different methods of authentication in your app then you can create a separate Area in your MVC project to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Either they are Admin user or the Normal Customer, You can have a Single Login Page at first. Then, Using the Information provided, you can identify whether he is Admin user or Normal Customer. Then, you can control the rest Like, Layouts, Menus, Permissions etc. I dont think you need to have 2 login pages at all.